# TemplateDoesNotExist at / in django

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

```
from .shortcuts import render
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def list_of_post(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    template = 'post/list_of_post.ht`enter code here`ml'
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

It should work.

Comment: From error log in screenshot the error is caused by home.html which is supposed to be templets/blog directory

Comment: Welcome to SO! Posting image of code/text instead of the code/text is discouraged at SO. Also a properly formatted question attracts more attention and response. You can learn how to better format you question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Pls show settings.py, urls.py
You have typo, try templets --> templates

Answer (score 0):

Like the error explains it can't find a file named 'home.html' in templets/blog/

Your home.html should be in the blog directory which is in templets.
Try adding it to the blog directory.